# How to call interface API from within COM server

Tags: visual-c++, com, atl

I have one com server with some interfaces exposing some API's

COM class looks like below

```
class ATL_NO_VTABLE CTask :
    public CComObjectRootEx<CComSingleThreadModel>,
    public CComCoClass<CTask, &CLSID_Task>,
    public ITask
{

public:
 STDMETHOD (Task)();
 STDMETHOD (ABC)();
...
}
```

Now this com server also contains one more class XYZ

ABC API needs to call XYZ functionality

```
 STDMETHODIMP ABC()
{
    XYZ xyz;
    xyz.dosomething();
}
```

dosomething function need to call com server Task function, like below

```
  class XYZ
       {
      public:
        void dosomething()
         {
        // need to call Task function
         }
        };
```

How can this be done? Do I need to CoCreateInstance ITask in dosomething?

I tried creating CTask taskl; in dosomething but it gave some errors.

Comment: "Gave some errors" doesn't help us help you.

Comment: Cannot create an instance of abstract class CTask.
Methods QueryInterface,AddRef,Release not implemented

Answer (score 0):

Class `CTask` is non-creatable since it doesn't implement `IUnknown` methods. You need to use one of `ATL` classes intended for serving as COM objects, for example `CComObject`:

```
CComPtr<ITask> newTask = new CComObject<CTask>();
```